# Bult-in WP_USERS vs Custom Users Table

Tags: wordpress

hope you all doing great.

I am building a platform using WordPress in which different services will be available for registered users.

I am not in a favor of using too many plugins, learned from one of my instructor. He told me if you can write the functionality why using the plugin. My previous background is in Core PHP, CodeIgniter & Laravel.

My concern is in my platform i will collect different information from Name, Email, SSN, Address, Employment Information and so on, should i use the built in wordpress users table, or i should go with mine custome table. I know that wordpress has an option for adding usermeta but isnt it a bad practice against database normalization. I was thinking about 3rd NF, I am in favor of building a complete custom system without using any plugin, for registration, login, order processing, services management and etc.

In general, i am too much confused.

Below is the data structure of database i have in mind.

Users Table
Employment Information Table, link to Users
Services Table, 
Orders Table, link to users, services
Billing Information Table, link to users

Lets suppose 
i want to save first,middle & last name, email, password, phone, ssn, address 1 & 2, city, state, zip code, employment information which could be more than one, if he has worked in more than one companies.
company name, address, contact, email, ein, annual salary, hours, rate, how often he get paid, monthly, quarterly or whatever.

Comment: You have to add some code dude; for context

Comment: Sir my concern is not about the code, its about the data structure, whether one should always use core wp users table even if he has too many fields to save or its purely depend on the nature of project,

For example, if i am using my own table, i can fetch all the fields in a single query without even using joins, but if i am using wp users, i'll have to execute one more query to get the extra meta data of users from another table. If one is already fetching data from 2 to 3 tables, is it necessary to add 1 more table in the query

Comment: This website is about programming/code questions.....

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic as it can generate answer based on opinions… Now a plugin as Woocommerce for example uses `wp_usermeta` table to store additional related customer user data (and many other plugins too)…